# Angular Material Table dataSource not binding correctly/updating, no errors yet nothing works

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

When inspecting served page:

```html
<table _ngcontent-c6="" class="mat-elevation-z8 mat-table" fxfill="" 
      mat-table="" matsort="" role="grid" ng-reflect-data-source="[object Object]">
```

In View:

```
table matSort fxfill mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8"
```

In Controller/Constructor:

```js
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.section1)
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

this.service.getSection1().subscribe(data => {
  this.section1 = data;
  console.log(this.section1);
})
```

I also made a function with a button that on click, changed datasource to "BookingId":"SomethingSomething" and when I click on it, it works.I do get intellisense errors and other stuff.

I also added console.log for dataSource in there and upon inspection, the data from the "section1" object is not being added to the dataSource.

I've been re-using a lot of my code from a previous project where everything works fine with this configuration.

I also have a "displayedColumns" object defined in my Controller + an interface model exported.

I'm testing this using only 1 row to make sure there's no misspelling or other small crap that's causing this.

Edit:

If I add this to the click function, the data is added correctly to the table even if intellisense does not like it:

```
this.service.getSection1().subscribe(data => {
  this.dataSource = data;
  console.log(this.section1)
})
```

Comment: When you're reassigning `this.section1` in the subscribe callback, you're only changing the local variable - not what the datasource has. I would pass the service into the datasource and have the datasource subscribe and update it's values instead.

Comment: @fredrik really? I thought that's how it's supposed to be done, it's weird as it works without a problem in the other app. I've been comparing the two and for the life of me I can't find a functional difference. 

How would I pass that into the datasource?

Thanks for the reply&time!

Comment: I just added this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.section1) after the this.section1 = data; seems to have worked, now I'm just confused as to why it worked in the other app.

Comment: You can experiment with my StackBlitz data table.  Make changes and see what happens.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries

Comment: @Preston thanks, that's table is quite nice! Definitely helps tweaking it here and there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.section1) after the this.section1 = data; seems to have worked, now I'm just confused as to why it worked in the other app.

A couple of days later I ended up rebuilding everything with redux and used the @select() decorator on the array in my store and then subscribed to it in the constructor. This works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, every time I hovered over the table, the attribute `ng-reflect-data-source="[object Object]` was added to the table.

I noticed that I was always loading the `dataSource` with a new instance of `MatTableDataSource`, similar to `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.section1)`.

Analyzing https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview and code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries?file=app%2Fmembers%2Fmembers.component.ts

I noticed that the dataSource instance was created once, `dataSource: MatTableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource;` and it was only updated, similar to `this.dataSource.data = this.section1`.

After making this change, the list is updated immediately after receiving the data.